# Converting base64 string to byte array fails with base64 string from iOS - "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string"

Tags: c#, ios, arrays, model-view-controller, base64

I have an MVC webapp with a function which is to upload an image to a server. The function works on Android and Windows, however it only partially works on iOS. On iOS, some images can be converted from base64 string to byte array, and some others can not. All images I have tested with are of type jpeg.

The image is retrieved via a file input and then encoded to a base64 string via javascript:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
reader.onload = function () {
    stringholder.value = reader.result;
    picholder.src = reader.result;
};
```

This base64 string is then passed to the controller, where it is converted to a byte array:

```
var split = Image01.Split(',');
string Image01_Type = split[0] + ",";
string Image01_B64String = split[1];
byte[] Image01_Data = Convert.FromBase64String(Image01_B64String);
```

Some images result in the following error when attempting the conversion from base64 string to byte array: "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string."

I cannot for the life of me figure out what is causing the error. The image file converts without error in javascript to base64 string, and the base64 strings themselves look fine.

Can anybody help me find out what is going wrong?

*Edit: The base64 string seems to be getting truncated when it is converted on iOS.

Comment: Compare the byte length of the string where it is create to the one you are using to convert to bytes.  Usually it is due to loosing characters at end of string.

Comment: You're on to something. The reader.result (in the javascript code) seems to return the correct result. However, that is then not being posted correctly to the controller, because the string in the controller is truncated. What could be the cause of this? Note that this only happens in iOS (both Chrome and Safari). Chrome on Android and Chrome, IE and Edge in Windows all work as expected.

Comment: Usually it is due to not including byte count when transferring a binary file over communication link.  In Net stream data is not received in one chunk.  So you have to continue reading until you get entire message.

Comment: Could you explain how I would do that? The entire (untruncated) base64 string is saved into an input element on the upload page. When I submit the form, how do I ensure that I get the untruncated string to my controller? The form is posted using Html.BeginForm(), with AntiForgeryToken.

Comment: Is the truncation occurring writing to form or reading from form?  First figure out where the issue is.

Comment: Hi again. Your guidance led me to the solution. I changed out the <input> in which I was storing the base64 string for a <textarea>, and that did the trick! The whole base64 string is now posted and converted correctly. Thanks for the help.